# How to align text to the right

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to align the `dashboardNewsItemDate` to the right, instead of on the left.  Currently it shows up immediately next to `dashboardNewsItemHeadline`.  I thought that putting it within a `TableRow` would make the `android:layout_gravity="right"` function as I'd like, but that's proven to be wrong.

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="center">
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/dashboardNewsItemHeadline" android:layout_gravity="left"
                />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/dashboardNewsItemDate" android:layout_gravity="right" android:autoText="false"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

In the end, my objective is for content so be displayed like this...

```
My news title                       Mar 3
-----------------------------------------
This is a bit of a longer news      Jul 2
title and it wraps
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, try regular "gravity" instead of "layout_gravity" for your TextViews.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work :-\

Answer (score 0):

The `layout_width="wrap_content"` in the last TextView is cancelling out the `gravity="right"`.  Change it to `fill_parent` or `match_parent` and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a magic attribute which should solve your problem:

```
android:stretchColumns="*"
```

Add this attribute to your `TableLayout`:

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:stretchColumns="*">
    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/dashboardNewsItemHeadline" android:layout_gravity="left"
                />
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Text"
                android:id="@+id/dashboardNewsItemDate" android:layout_gravity="right" android:autoText="false"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```